# How to Set DataGridView Row Tag

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, tags

I am using a double click event on a listview that will add three columns to a datagridview. I'm not sure how to set the "Tag" property on the "selectedText" variable.

```
Private Sub lwArticles_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles lwArticles.DoubleClick
    Dim selectedText = lwArticles.SelectedItems(0).SubItems.Item(0).Text 'Article No
    Dim selectedDesc = lwArticles.SelectedItems(0).SubItems.Item(1).Text 'Description
    Dim currRowNo As String = ""
    Dim alreadyExists = False

    For i As Integer = 0 To dgvDetail.Rows.Count - 1
        currRowNo = dgvDetail.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
        If currRowNo = selectedText Then
            alreadyExists = True
            dgvDetail.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value += 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    'If the entry doesn't exist, add it
    If Not alreadyExists Then
        dgvDetail.Rows.Add(New String() {selectedText, selectedDesc, 1})
    End If

End Sub
```

After this I loop through the row's tags to see the article numbers. It will be near my dgvDetail.Rows.Add() that I should be setting the Tag property to equal the selectedText ... Any one know how to do this?

Edit:
The datagridview columns being populated are: "Article Number", "Description" and "Quantity". The quantity is set in the loop, basically if I've double clicked on the same thing twice, it will increment the third column (Cell(2)) by one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Add "function" for the DataGridView control returns the index of the row in the grid, so you can try using that to reference the row:

```
Dim rowIndex As Integer
rowIndex = dgvDetail.Rows.Add(New String() {selectedText, selectedDesc, 1})
dgvDetails.Rows(rowIndex).Tag = selectedText
```